# Is there a way to conditionally handle a const in a separate js file with react navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following in my React Native app:

`Hub.js`:

```
export default class Hub extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Links")}
                        >
                            <Text>Link #1</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Links")}>
                            <Text>Link #2</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

`webviewsFolder/Links.js`:

```
export default function Links() {

    const links = ['https://www.youtube.com/', 'https://www.google.com/'];

    return <WebView source={{ uri: links[0] }} />;
}
```

I want to set up my app so that clicking on the `Link #1` button causes `Links.js` to return youtube (aka links[0]), and clicking on the `Link #2` button causes `Links.js` to return google (links[1]). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a parameter along with navigation

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Links",{site:"Youtube"})
```

or

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Links",{site:"Google"})
```

And in Links.js

```
export default function Links({route}) {

    const link = route.params.site==='Google'?'https://www.google.com/':'https://www.youtube.com/';

    return <WebView source={{ uri: link }} />;
}
```

You can have a switch or even pass the url directly from the other component and use it in links component.

Comment: I got an error saying "Can't find variable: route"

Comment: You are navigating using react navigation right ?

Comment: Yes, not sure if it helps but these are my import statements:


`import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();`

Comment: May i know how you are using Links in navigator ?

Comment: You can check this sample https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/5b84d0

Comment: I'm having a new problem with this route.params.site. It's too big of a question to put in a single comment so I made a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412680/how-should-route-param-constants-be-separated-in-js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232023/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-klg).